# Find the N'th highest number in unsorted array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Today in a interview, I was told to write a program which will output the nth highest number in the unsorted array,

I solved this using javascript, the program is as follows,

```
var fn50 = function(){
    var reverseSort = function(myArray,highest){
        var x = 0,
            y = 0,
            z = 0,
            temp = 0,
            totalNum = myArray.length, // total numbers in array
            flag = false, // is the numbers sorted in reverse while iteration
            isAchieved = false; // whether we achieved the nth highest

        while(x < totalNum){
            y = x + 1; // start comparing 'yth' number which is next to 'xth' number.

            if(y < totalNum){
                // start comparing 'xth' with the next number, and if 'xth' number less than its next position number, just swipe them
                for(z = y; z < totalNum; z++){

                    if(myArray[x] < myArray[z]){
                        temp = myArray[z];
                        myArray[z] = myArray[x];
                        myArray[x] = temp;
                        flag = true; // if number swiping done ?
                    }else{
                        continue;
                    }   
                }                   
            }

            if(flag){
                flag = false;
            }else{
                x++; // x holds the max number in series, now move to next position to find next highest number 
                if(x > highest){ // if x is what the desired max number which we want flag it and break the loop to escape further iteration.
                    isAchieved = true;
                }   
            }
            if(isAchieved){
                break;
            }
        }

        print(myArray[(highest - 1)]);  
    };

    reverseSort([12,56,78,34,11,100,95],4); // passing the unsorted array of number's, and finding the 4th highest number
};

fn50();
```

I got the desired output i.e the answer is 56 from the above array which is the 4th highest number.

But the interviewer told for a better solution.

Can you tell me or give me a hint, how can there be a better solution.
Some data structure technique ?

Comment: Umm, is this more complicated than just sorting the array, then taking the 4th element from the result? As in `arr.sort()[3]`? And why would you write your own sort when the language already has one?

Comment: @torazaburo It would have to be `arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a-b; })` as `.sort()` does a lexical sort

Comment: @Andreas sure, you're right, that was pseudo-code.

Answer (score 7):

Sorting and selecting the `k`th highest number needs `O(n log(n))` time, where `n` is the number of elements. In the bibliography, there is the [medians of medians algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians), that allows us to select the `k`th highest or smallest in linear time, no matter what value `k` has. You could find out if the interviewer had this kind of algorithm in mind, if you asked if the desired element could be the median of the array. The median is the element at position `n / 2`, which is considered the hardest case.

But for an interview, it's a complicated algorithm. If `k` is in general small, you can apply the following algorithm, based on the structure of a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). You convert the array into a heap in linear time. Then you extract `k` times the largest element. This will take `O(n + k * log(n))` time, which for small `k = ο(n / log(n)` is linear.

Having `k` be as small as a constant number, like 4, has an even simpler linear algorithm. Every time we scan the array and remove the largest. This will take `O(k * n)` time and because `k` is constant, `O(k * n) = O(n)`.

Comment: >Every time we scan the array and remove the largest. This will take O(k * n) time and because k is constant, O(k * n) = O(n).  Wouldn't that be inefficient in the real world, because removing from the start of array would cause a shift of all remaining elements?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to implement this with quickselect [as JuniorCompressor suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29579338/30433).
But I wonder if that is really the fastest possible way. I guess the calculation of the pivot could be made more efficient.

```
var nthLargest = function(list, n) {
  var i, a = 0, b = list.length, m, pivot;
  if(n < 1) throw new Error("n too small");
  if(list.length < n) throw new Error("n too large");
  list = list.slice(0);
  var swap = function(list, a, b) {
    var temp = list[a];
    list[a] = list[b];
    list[b] = temp;
  }
  //returns the index of the first element in the right sublist
  var partition = function(list, pivot, a, b) {
    b--;
    while(a <= b) {
      if(list[a] <= pivot) a++;
      else if(list[b] > pivot) b--;
      else swap(list, a, b);
    }
    return a;
  }
  while(b - a > 1) {
    for(i = a, pivot = 0; i < b; i++) {
      pivot += list[i];
    }
    pivot /= b-a;
    m = partition(list, pivot, a, b);
    if(b - m >= n) a = m; // select right sublist
    else { // select left sublist
      if(m === b) return list[a]; // all elements in sublist are identical
      n -= b - m;
      b = m;
    }
  }
  if(n !== 1) throw new Error();
  return list[a];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    function nthlargest(array, highest) {
        array.sort();
        l=array.length;
        if(highest>l)
            return("undefined");
        else
            return(array[l-highest+1]);
    }
    document.write(nthlargest([23, 652, 43, 89, 23, 90, 99, 88], 2));
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is the simplest way I can think of.

But it appears you created your own sorting implementation.

Why not use the `Array.sort` function?

```
function nthHighest(numbers, n) {
    var sorted = numbers.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });
    return sorted[sorted.length - n];
}
```

You could simplify the arithmetic by doing a reverse sort, which just means `b - a` instead of `a - b`, then you don't need to pull from the back, which is just a cosmetic improvement.

```
function nthHighest(numbers, n) {
    var sorted = numbers.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b - a;
    });
    return sorted[n - 1];
}
```

You could also iterate over the array once, copying each element into a new array in sorted order and again, taking the Nth to last element, using underscore to implement a binary search.

```
function nthHighest(numbers, n) {
    var sorted = [];
    numbers.forEach(function (number) {
        sorted.splice(_.sortedIndex(sorted, number), 0, number);
    });
    return sorted[numbers.length - n];
}
```

But this is basically a spin on the same concept: sort and take N.  This approach would also perform better with a linked list than a pure array due to the restructuring, but that can be a separate exercise.

Comment: Sorting may be the simplest way, but not the fastest one, as JuniorCompressor [explained](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29579338/1529630).

Comment: They didn't say faster, they said better.  It's not clear what that means.  Sorting is almost never the fastest way to do anything.

Comment: It was an interview question, for heaven's sake. Unless he was interviewing for a job at Google, they mainly wanted to see if his brain was functioning. I doubt if they expected him to have mastered Knuth's four volumes of semi-numerical algorithms. My guess is, the answer of "sort (using the built-in sort) and take the fourth element" would have scored 100%.

Comment: I agree, that is why I am helping find simpler ways to sort (meaning less code) than try to optimize every nanosecond of performance out of it.  I'd be surprised if an interviewer really expected a computationally faster answer than sorting.

Comment: @Brandon, not really. When questions on algorithms are asked, the term "better" means less time complexity. `Array.sort` internally runs 2 `for` loops   which is worst case `O(2n)` - that means for n items in an array, you will have a code that will execute `n*n` times to get the result. This is considered bad. It would be nicer if the complexity could be reduced to `O(n)` or `O(n*log(n))`

Answer (score 1):

I came up with my own solution as it goes:

```
const nthlargest = (arr, n) => {
    let newArr = [arr[0]];
    for (let index = 1; index < arr.length; index++) {
        const element = arr[index];
        // push to end
        if (element > newArr[index - 1]) {
            newArr.push(element);
        } else {
            let insertPos = 0;
            // if greater than first and less than last
            if (newArr[0] < element && element < newArr[index - 1]) {
                for (let j = 0; j < newArr.length; j++) {
                    if (newArr[j] > element) {
                        insertPos = j;
                    }
                }
            }
            //insert at specified pos
            newArr.splice(insertPos, 0, element);
        }
    }
    return newArr[n];
}

console.log(nthlargest([43, 56, 23, 89, 88, 90, 99, 652], 4));
// counting from 0
// 89
```

This is without sorting the original array else it would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

using the sort array method

```
function nthLargest(array, n){

    array.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b - a; //organises the array in descending organises
      });

    let i = n - 1; //i is the index of the nth largest number
    
    console.log(array[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def funcc(arr, n):
    max=0
    k=0
    while (n>0):
        n-=1
        for i in arr:
            if (i>max):
                max=i
        if(n>0):
            arr.remove(max)
            max=0
    return max
```

a = [1,2,3,4,19,10,5,11,22,8]
k = funcc(a, 3)
print(k)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [30, 8, 2, 350, 4, 63, 98];
let max = 0;
var nth = 5;
for (let i = 0; i < nth; i++) {
  max = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (data[j] > max) {
      max = data[j];
    }
  }
  var ind = data.indexOf(max);
  console.log(data);
  const key = data.slice(ind, ind + 1);
}
console.log(nth + " largest number is ", max);
```